# Looking for a free and light HTML parsing

Tags: c, html-parsing

I need to get some values of HTML web page. I want only the value of `value` of `input` tag filtered by name or id or class(if supports XPath is welcome too). It's very simple thing, for this reason I'm looking for a "non-complex" parser, because I want no tons of code in my program(I'd used one like this) it must be free, light and fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use libxml2. Despite its name it includes a HTML parser [HTML Parser module - libxml2](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html).
I have used the python binding, it's fast and supports XPath.

Comment: How do I install it on windows?

Comment: Instructions to install libxml2 on windows are available here : http://www.zlatkovic.com/libxml.en.html

Comment: Thanks. Can you give me simple code examples how to use it?